# ASP.NET 4 WebApi: route with back slash

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a WebApi-route `api/{type}({id})/{prop}`
and I want to call it with url like `/api/User(domain\username)/groups` - the key point is "\" in `id` value. I send it from the client url-encoded i.e. as: 
`api/User(domain%5Cusername)/groups`. But the route is ignored and I'm getting 404.

How to pass back slash into a route's argument?

Comment: Does it work without the backslash? I've never seen multiple parameters in a uri segment.

Comment: @ATerry Sure. Url `api/User(username)/groups` leads to the route.

Comment: I haven't found a solution, but what I am noticing is that IIS is screwing this up, not Asp. It has to do with the url rewrite module. When I test this, I get a 404 from the IIS static file handler, not a 404 from web api. Also, if I look at the "requested url" in the error, it decoded the backslash and converted it to a forward slash. Maybe try writing a rewrite rule or using a pipe or some other non-reserved character.

Comment: @ATerry you're right - the problem is in IIS, it decodes and replaces "\" to "/".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @ATerry suggested in comments the problem is not with ASP.NET but in HTTP.SYS + IIS. Back-slashes are replaced by HTTP.SYS onto forward-slashes even before coming to IIS.
We can work this around with help of UrlRewrite IIS-module as it has access to original (undecoded) url.

For my example I came up with the following rule.

```
<rule name="allow backslash" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="api/(.*)\((.*)\)(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="api/{R:1}({C:1}{C:2}{C:3}){R:3}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{UNENCODED_URL}" pattern="\((.*)(%5C)(.*)\)" />
    </conditions>
</rule>
```

It's not ideal as it's very specific. It'd more useful to have a generic rule which just processes `%5C`.

The idea is to catch an url with `%5C` and rewrite it to put it back. It's a little bit weird but it works.

Besides the rule we need to set `allowDoubleEscaping=false` in `system.webServer`/`security`/`requestFiltering`:

```
    <security>
        <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true">
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

With this rule the value come into a Mvc/Api controller will be encoded (with %). So we'll have to decode it:

```
public virtual DomainResult GetObjectProp(string type, string id, string prop)
{
        id = Uri.UnescapeDataString(id);
}
```

Comment: Finally got this working myself using the same method. I should add that it's not really IIS at fault, but Http.sys that does the cleansing. IIS is able to pull the unencoded url and do a rewrite.